# How to auto refresh data table when new record is inserted?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my code in data table fetching record:

```
<section class="content">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
 </div>
 <div class="box-body">
 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 <thead>
 <th>ID</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Course</th>
  <th>Purpose</th>
  <th>Time-in</th>
 <th>Time-out</th>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  include_once('Connection.php');
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  ?>
  <tr>
 <td><?php  echo $row['id']?></td>
 <td><?php  echo $row['date']?></td>
 <td> <?php echo $row['name']?></td>
 <td> <?php echo $row['course']?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['purpose']?></td>
<td> <?php echo $row['time-in']?> </td>
<td>
<?php echo $row['time-out']?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php }}?>
 </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
   </div>
   </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

This is the javascript I use:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#box-body').load('data.php')
            }, 2000);
        });
    </script>
```

Is there a way to auto refresh my data table when a new record is inserted?

I tried echoing my data table in separate note pad and calling it by div in my javascript code but it does not work.

Comment: Where is your insert data code?

Comment: You can refresh page after some interval so new data show in tablw

Comment: You have to add trigger in insert row data code. So, when you are adding new row it will update table. No need to do this in setInterval as it will run continuously although there is no change in data. It will cost on page load

Comment: i dont have yet code for inserting data , i just manually insert records in phpmyadmin to try my code if it works.

Comment: can u guys show me some  code example on how i can auto refresh my data table ?

Comment: If you don't have any code for inserting data but do it manually, you will need to check if there are any new data inserted on a regular basis. You could do that using Ajax. You can then send in the last ID you have in your table and only get any ID's that's higher than the current one. That way, you'll only get new records which you then return to your Ajax request and can append it to the table. I can't give you "some code example" since it would be too much. The question is simply too broad. Now you have an idea so do some research and try something.

Comment: thank you for giving me some hints i'll try it.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `<script>` tags if i may ask?

Comment: Sorry,  i mistakenly copy the another scipt tag. I'll just update it

Answer (score 0):

The table should be ajax-based if you want to update data without page refresh.
You should use **Jquery datatables server-side processing** scenario to do so and Here's the complete method for it:

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side